# SDK version and installation in Websphere 8.5.5.13

Tags: sdk, websphere, pega

I have installed WebSphere 8.5.5 and then updated it to WAS 8.5.5.13 .

Now I am installing SDK 8.0.3 , it is not installing saying

Your operating system failed the prerequisites check because it is below the recommended minimum level for this product. For more information about supported operating systems, see the IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition Version 8.0 detailed system requirements Web pages - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045339

Please let me know how should I proceed further.

Comment: Have you read the error message or the list of supported operating system releases?

Comment: Also... what is your operating system?

Comment: the operating system is Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

The issue is sorted.
SDK 8 will not work windows 2008.
It is not supported by windows 2008.